# Remove required API Key from function positional arguments in generated SDK when using API Key-based Authentication

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I’m using swagger-codegen to generate a python client SDK from an OpenAPI 3.0 spec.

My API uses API Key-based Authentication as described here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/

For each operation, the API Key is a query param called `api_key`.

`api_key` is a required parameter at the HTTPS level.

When I generate a python client SDK from the spec using the community-built python generator, `api_key` is still included in each function as a required positional argument. This is not desired behavior, as `api_key` is already taken care of by the API Key auth scheme.

When I set `api_key` to be NOT required for each operation, the SDK works properly, in the sense that a user can make a request without passing in `api_key` as a function argument. However, this is a suboptimal solution, as I do want `api_key` to be flagged as required (as it is a required parameter at the HTTPS level), and removing the required flag now makes my API Docs incorrect.

My question: is there any way to leave `api_key` flagged as required, so that my docs are correct, but have the Python SDK generator not include `api_key` as a required positional argument for each operation function.

I am open to customizing the mustache templates, but have not been able to find any metadata in the intermediate representation (that is generated by swagger-codegen and passed to the mustache templates) that would enable me to skip `api_key` when defining each function's arguments in mustache. I am also open to switching over to openapi-generator if that would solve the issue.

I know I can theoretically fork the generator and add an `is_api_key` boolean to each parameter based on whether its name is "api_key", but I would really prefer to avoid that route.

Has anyone run into this issue and found a solution?

Thanks! I greatly appreciate any insight into this!

Comment: Just to clarify - does the `parameters` section in operations explicitly define a query parameter named `api_key`? If yes, you need to remove this parameter and use the `security` section instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the issue perfectly.